# mysql multiple values () include, need update based on condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update the fields on duplicate key if one columns value is equal to soemthing. Right now I have something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (metric,amount,something1,something2)
VALUES              (metric,amount,something1,something2),
                    (metric,amount,something1,something2),
                    (metric,amount,something1,something2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
amount = IF (metric = '6', amount = amount + ( '"+amount+"'),'')
         ELSEIF (metric = '8' ,     amount = amount + ( '"+impressions+"') ,'')  
         ELSEIF (metrtic = '11' ,   amount = amount + ( '"+impressions+"') ,'');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you wan to insert data or update data?

Comment: I want to insert it, and if the insert has the same key update it.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? that really help  Which colnum is you DUPLICATE KEY condition?

Comment: I couldn't provide actual data. Key is generated by a website's url + date of which something happened + metric (of which are 3  different ones that are related to this and country code). The information is grouped by websites and country codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventually worked for me is:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (metric,amount,something1,something2)
VALUES              (metric,amount,something1,something2),
                    (metric,amount,something1,something2),
                    (metric,amount,something1,something2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                metric = VALUES(metric),
                amount = amount + VALUES (amount),
                modified = NOW(),
                something1= VALUES(something1);
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `UPDATE` , self `JOIN` With `CASE WHEN`

`[DUPLICATE KEY]` can fill you want to check `DUPLICATE` column.

```
UPDATE `table` r
JOIN (
    SELECT Count(*) cnt,[DUPLICATE KEY] 
    from `table`
    group by [DUPLICATE KEY]
) t1 on r.[DUPLICATE KEY] = t1.[DUPLICATE KEY] and t1.cnt > 1
SET r.amount = (CASE WHEN r.metric = '6' THEN r.amount+ ( '"+amount+"'),'' 
                  WHEN r.metric = '8' THEN r.amount + ( '"+impressions+"') ,''
                  WHEN r.metric = '11' THEN r.amount+ ( '"+impressions+"') ,''
                  ELSE r.amount
            END)
```

Comment: i run a single insert sql, and if there is a duplicate by a unique key (which happens on some occasions) then update the already inserted data by adding the new data. This wouln't work i think. I have "(values, values,values) , (values,values,values) ON DUPLICATE KEY "; kind of insert.